# Add wildcard ssl in multiple ec2

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, iis, amazon-ec2

**Problem Summary:**

Hi i have one wildcard ssl which is installed in IIS on AWS EC2 instance.
This is working fine

Now i need to create another EC2 instance and use same ssl to the new instance IIS.

**Current Stage:**

I created new instance and installed IIS and working fine. I have http and https inbound access so currently i can access default IIS page from outside with instance public address.

Now i installed same SSL certificate in the IIS. I configured ssl in my new website and done. But this is not working. When i try with https i got 404.

Please help me to identify the issues.

1. Any restriction to use wildcard in multiple instances' IIS in same account
2. Any correct method to do this? I don't dont want load balancer now

***Update:***

I tried to configure in my local machine.

**Step 1:** I created a sample WebAPI and run in 8090 port with http. It shows like below as expected.
[image: Sample Web with http (not have host name)]

**Step 2:** I added https bindings with my ssl certificate but not gave any host name.
[image: Binding Configuration]
[image: Sample Web with https(not have host name]

**Step 3:** Now I added sample host name (ssltest.mydomain)
[image: Binding Configuration]
[image: Sample Web with https]

I didn't get any idea on this. Please help

Comment: Whenever there is a clear status code, start from https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/943891/the-http-status-code-in-iis-7-0-iis-7-5-and-iis-8-0

Answer (score 0):

> Any restriction to use wildcard in multiple instances' IIS in same account

There are no restrictions on how often a certificate can be used

> Any correct method to do this?

There is nothing special about it, i.e. there is no difference between installing two different certificates on two hosts or the same certificate on two hosts. You likely did something wrong but it is unclear what exactly.

Note that a HTTP response code 404 actually means that the certificate itself is working since otherwise you would get a certificate error which comes before the HTTP response. So there is likely some misconfiguration which is not related to the certificate.